# Convert Powershell results to an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, datatable

I am using the [Write-datatable](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2fdeaf8d-b164-411c-9483-99413d6053ae#content) from Microsoft Technet.

But I am having a problem in that the data I need to input is not in an array format, I believe it is an object e.g.

My data looks like this

```
FirstName : john  
SecondName : smith  
Number : 1234
```

And I believe I need it to look like this

```
FirstName   SecondName   Number  
---------   ----------   ------  
john         smith        1234
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: How are you making the call? Where does your input come from? Post your code. You can look at the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver.aspx for SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer, that is what that script calls to write the datatable - your $Data parameter must be one of the accepted types.

Comment: That script appears to be expecting input in the form of a datatable, not an array....

Comment: @mjolinor - it will also take a DataRow array and any object that implements IDataReader.

Comment: Then you need to create a datarow from your object.

Answer (score 0):

Looking the [Write-DataTable](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2fdeaf8d-b164-411c-9483-99413d6053ae#content) function the `$data` parameter is used as an uniq parameter to the method `WriteToServer()` of an object from the class [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx). According to Microsoft documentation `$data` should be a DataRow array, a DataTable or a IDataReader.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So you have a powershell object, let's call it a person object, that has member properties of 'FirstName','SecondName', and 'Number'. So when you go:

```
$person.FirstName
$person.SecondName
$person.Number
```

the output should be

```
John
Smith
1234
```

Can't you do something like this to make the person object to an array of strings object

```
$array = @()
$person | get-member -MemberType Property | % {$array += $person.($_.Name)}
```

That will put your array in a weird order. So I guess you'll need to hard code the order.

```
$array = @()
$order = 'FirstName','SecondName','Number'
$order | % {$array += $person.$_}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found creating a new .NET datatable and then passing the data to it worked, thanks for the pointers everyone

```
    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2 = New-Object System.Data.DataTable

    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.Columns.Add("Date")  | Out-Null
    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.Columns.Add("Name")  | Out-Null
    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.Columns.Add("Model")  | Out-Null
    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.Columns.Add("Manufacturer")  | Out-Null
    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.Columns.Add("Description")  | Out-Null
    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.Columns.Add("DNSHostName")  | Out-Null
    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.Columns.Add("Domain")  | Out-Null
    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.Columns.Add("DomainRole", [int])  | Out-Null
    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.Columns.Add("PartOfDomain")  | Out-Null
    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.Columns.Add("NumberOfProcessors", [int])  | Out-Null
    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.Columns.Add("SystemType")  | Out-Null
    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.Columns.Add("TotalPhysicalMemory")  | Out-Null

$Data_BOX_ComputerSystem | ForEach-Object {
    $row = $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.NewRow()
    $row.Item('Date') = get-date -format G
    $row.Item('Name') = $_.Name.ToString()
    $row.Item('Model') = $_.Model.ToString()
    $row.Item('Manufacturer') = $_.Manufacturer.ToString()
    $row.Item('Description') = $_.Description.ToString()
    $row.Item('DNSHostName') = $_.DNSHostName.ToString()
    $row.Item('Domain') = $_.Domain.ToString()
    $row.Item('DomainRole') = $_.DomainRole.ToString()
    $row.Item('PartOfDomain') = $_.PartOfDomain.ToString()
    $row.Item('NumberOfProcessors') = $_.NumberOfProcessors.ToString()
    $row.Item('SystemType') = $_.SystemType.ToString()
    $row.Item('TotalPhysicalMemory') = $_.TotalPhysicalMemory.ToString()
    $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2.Rows.Add($row)}

    WriteDataTable server database table $Data_BOX_ComputerSystem2
```